# Add new property to news documents on Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a voting system. For this the client cannot send `votes: 0` because he could modify this to any number.

How can I add `votes: 0` for new documents or detect that this property is not 0 and cancel it (prefer the first approach) from Firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use security rules different document methods such as using a certain rule for create and another for update.

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /votes/{voteId} {
            allow create: if request.resource.data.votes == 0
            allow update: if request.resource.data.votes == resource.data.votes
        }
    }
}
```

This would mean a user could create a vote but they have to set `votes` to `0` and you can update a vote document but `votes` would need to equal the current value. You would also want to look at other rules such as

`request.resource.data.size() == 1` to limit the fields in the document being added
`request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['field_1','field_2'])` to ensure it has all the fields necessary to update/create the document.

Comment: Good info. With this I'd have cover the security part but what about when the user needs to vote up some document? It'd need to be +1 or -1 and we're saying here that the votes need to be equal to the ones we have already, right?

Comment: You have a few option, using Frank's suggestion you would do a transaction and amend the security rule to say `request.resource.data.votes == resource.data.votes + 1` or you can use another collection to store the vote and then using a cloud function have it update the main document in a trusted environment but still using transactions to ensure consistency

Comment: with a "cloud function" you mean a function that you have in rules? I have some functions for example to detect if the uses is logged or not but not sure if those cloud functions are something different (sorry, don't really have too much experience with Firebase)

Answer (score 2):

This should be a fairly basic combination of [reading data from the collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) and then performing [transactions of batched updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). If you're having trouble implementing this, show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Definitely also implement [Jack's security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53281795/209103), as those will prevent having to do this again in the future.

Comment: hmmm, not sure if I follow you... this should be written on the client side, right? Maybe you're pointing a normal get and post to the ddbb? If so, that's fine, I'm getting at the moment some date and also updating the user but now I have this new property which requires some extra security rules

Comment: The code to backfill the existing documents can be run on a client, or on a server/Cloud Functions using an Admin SDK. It doesn't really matter where it runs, since you're likely to only run it once, if you follow the advice from Jack.